# Azure PaaS and Continous Integration

Tags: azure

I am planning to use Microsoft Azure Cloud Services to host my application, the staging/production instances are handled nicely with Azure.

However, usually we need to run git and a CI service(Jenkins or CruizeControl.Net) to create the automated builds. Where this would fit in Azure Cloud Services, if I chose to host my app on a VM i would place them there, but since i decided to go the Cloud Services road i don't have a server i could use as a build server, what are my options?

PS We're not running TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure Web Sites has git / tfs integration (local git, github, bitbucket, tfs).

But... since you're targeting Cloud Services: You'll need to create your builds on a Windows-based machine.  You'll then be able to automate not only the build, but the packaging of the cspkg file (you can call the command-line tool [cspack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx) to package the build for Azure, upload it with [csupload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg466228.aspx), then use PowerShell or the cross-platform [command line tools](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/) to do a deployment upgrade (choosing either staging or production).

I like the idea of uploading the deployment packages, naming each one uniquely and keeping a historical library of the various build deployments (and matching configuration files). This works well if I need to roll back to a prior instance (of course staging lets you do this, but you may choose not to run staging 24/7).

Hope this helps...

Comment: so i would get a small or extra small virtual machine, put the git and the cruise control there, and then build and publish to the cloud service, is this natural?

Comment: Or you could sign up for the free TFS service in the cloud and migrate your ci/build/deployment stuff

Comment: You can nicely combine git and TeamCity and build/deploy your branches from TeamCity using powershell.